# UIScrollView dragging affected by UIWindow transform rotation

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, transform, uiwindow

I'm adding a video out function to my iPad app and have run into a problem with my UIScrollView.  To get the proper view orientation on the external monitor, I've rotated the UIWindow based on the current interface orientation (e.g. - mirroredScreenWindow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI * 0.5);).

The problem I've run into is that the ScrollView dragging seems to be affected by the UIWindow transform.  If the UIWindow is rotated 90 degrees, horizontal drags scroll the view vertically and vice versa.  Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from Apple Dev Support that said essentially, "Doing a transform on UIWindow will confuse the internal objects and should never be done."

Looks like I'll just have to create a modified ViewController that lays out all of my UI elements specifically for the format of the external screen, rather than just transforming the view controller that already works correctly on the iPad screen.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll views seem to maintain their own hidden transform.  You can try examining it, and see if there's any difference between when instantiating and adding the scroll view before or after modifying the window transform.

Comment: Examining the various transforms still leads me to the window transform as the culprit for this behavior, but I'm at a loss as to how to rectify this.

Comment: The viewController transform, the scrollView transform, and the scrollView subView transforms are all identical, regardless of the current window transform.  The window transform is the only one that changes and still it changes the scrollView drag behavior.  When the UIWindow is rotated 90 degrees, horizontal and vertical swipes are swapped.  When the UIWindow is rotated 180 degrees, the swipe directions are inverted (finger drags left = view moves right, etc).